# set decimal places of sum in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, decimal

I have a database I use for a debating competition I am trying to sort the standings out to see which schools will play off in the finals at the end of the semester.

I have this working as shown below however I am not able to round the ptc field, it currently returns up to 4 decimal places eg 0.6667 if they have won 2 out of 3 debates.

```
    SELECT   t.id,
             t.name                  AS name,
             SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid) AS w,
             SUM(t.id != d.winnerid) AS l,
             SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)/(SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)+SUM(t.id != d.winnerid)) AS ptc
    FROM     debates AS d
        JOIN teams   AS t ON t.id IN (d.hostid, d.visitid)
    WHERE    d.visitid != -1
         AND d.debatedate < CURDATE()
    GROUP BY t.id
    ORDER BY ptc DESC
```

I believe I have to use decimal(2,2) here however I am not able to get the syntax right I have tried a few diferent things like

```
SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)/(SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)+SUM(t.id != d.winnerid)) AS ptc decimal (2,2)
```

Am happy to provide more information about the tables if required but I don't think it is required?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cash), 2)
FROM <tablename>
```

If you are getting no results, then there must be a null value, try this instead.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cash), 2)
FROM<tablename> a
WHERE cash IS NOT NULL
```

Here is a simple demo of it :

**Update :**

```
 SELECT round( ROUND(SUM(p.prod_price = l.prod_unit_price), 2)
/ROUND(SUM(p.prod_id = l.prod_id), 2),2)
FROM b2b.product_master p
join b2b.move_cart_item_master l;
```

Comment: I tried covering what you had into my demo but am not quite sure how to do it?

Comment: ((SELECT ROUND((SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)/(SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)+SUM(t.id != d.winnerid)))), 2) FROM debates)  AS ptc

Comment: You will have to use `ROUND(SUM(t.id = d.winnerid), 2)` on each time, because if you don't use every time then it may be possible to not get expected data due to query problem.

Comment: @ak85 - My Pleasure, Keep Smiling.. :)

Answer (score 2):

For the ptc field Round, 2 decimal place...

Repalce

This line,

```
SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)/(SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)+SUM(t.id != d.winnerid)) AS ptc
```

To,

This Line!

```
ROUND(SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)/(SUM(t.id  = d.winnerid)+SUM(t.id != d.winnerid)),2) AS ptc
```